# TWIG - variable == objectattribute

Tags: arrays, symfony, for-loop, twig

I am new to Twig and Symfony2 (and PHP as well). I currently have an array of objects where I can access an attribute by doing {{result.attribute1}} after a {for result in results} statement.

I would like to use a variable  {{var| removePath}} (where removePath is an extension I made in Twig), and use it to iterate over the results array. What I would like to do is return the row `if {{var| removePath}} == result.attribute1`.

Is this possible to do in Twig? If so, how should I approach this? I have already tried something similar to the code found below, but the "else" statement is executed (saying there's no match). I also tried `var == result.attribute`, but this didn't work either.

```
{% for result in results %} 
{% if var|removePath in result.attribute1 %}
   {{ var | removePath }} exists.
{% else %}
   {{ var | removePath }} doesn't exist in array.
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Thus I think I have 2 questions;

1) Is it possible in TWIG (if so, how)

2) Is there an easier/better way to get the whole row (object array also contains attributes 2, 3 & 4, and I would like to return those that are in common with attribute 1 (if it matches var))

[See schema of my array](http://i39.tinypic.com/dcefld.png) **recently added**

Thank you in advance for your help! I hope my question is understandable :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just surround the expression with brackets.

use `(var|removePath)` which groups an expression.

example:

```
{% if ( 1+1 ) == 2 %}
```

And you can use the `attribute()` function to access properties and methods of an object/array.

```
{{ attribute(object, method) }}
{{ attribute(object, method, arguments) }}
{{ attribute(array, item) }}
```

[attribute chapter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) in the twig docs.

Further shorten template code using the ternary operator like this:

```
{% set strippedVar = var|removePath %}
{{ strippedVar }}{{ (strippedVar in result.attribute1) ? 'exists' : 'does not exist' }}.
```

Setting the filtered variable to another prevents executing the filter multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I still have "doesn't exist in array" being printed on the page.

Comment: what is your `var` variable? and are your "attributes" the array keys of the array holding the objects ? And what type is the result of `var|removePath` ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I've tried the ternary operator, and it works (no error messages), but "does not exist" still shows up (thus still no match). I have displayed both var|removePath and printed all result.attribute1's, and I see that there IS an identical match. Not sure why it isn't seeing it :S

Comment: what type is `result.attribute1` , an array ?

Comment: var = url of current page (result.attribute1 also = url). keys for results is indexes (0,1,2,3...). keys for result array is attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 (this sequence repeats itself for each key in results). (sorry it took so long, had to look up how to check things). A single "=" operator gave me an error "Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" ("end of statement block" expected)".

Comment: I am able to print keys for result.attribute1 (albeit seemingly random integers), so I think it might be an array (sorry, couldn't find "actual" tests to use).